# How to cancel an ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, cancellation

I wrote an application that runs some threads using `ExecutorService` and waits until they finish like this:

```
ExecutorService exService;
exService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
exService.execute(T1);
exService.execute(T2);
exService.shutdown();
boolean finshed = exService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

sometimes I need to cancel the execution of these threads (The entire `ExecutorService`).
I tried `exService.shutdownNow()` but it throws `java.lang.InterruptedException` and doesn't cancel threads.
How can I cancel execution of these threads?

---

EDIT: T1 class code added as nanda's request

```
public class TC implements Runnable{
    private ExtractedDataBuffer Buffer;
    private Scraper scraper;
    private String AppPath;
    private boolean Succeed=false;
    private Map<String,Object> Result=null;
    private JLabel StatElement;

    public TC(ExtractedDataBuffer Buffer,String AppPath,String XMLfile,JLabel Stat) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.Buffer = Buffer;
        this.AppPath=AppPath;
        this.StatElement=Stat;

        ScraperConfiguration config;
        config = new ScraperConfiguration(AppPath + Main.XMLFilesPath +XMLfile);
        scraper = new Scraper(config, AppPath);
    }

    private void extract(){
        try{
            mainF.SetIconStat("working", this.StatElement);
            scraper.execute();
            if(scraper.getStatus()==Scraper.STATUS_FINISHED){
                this.Succeed=true;
                Map<String,Object> tmp=new HashMap<String,Object>();
                tmp.put("UpdateTime", ((Variable) scraper.getContext().get("UpdateTime")).toString().trim());
                Buffer.setVal(this.Result);
                mainF.SetIconStat("done", this.StatElement);
            }else{
                this.Succeed=false;
                this.Result=null;
                Buffer.setVal(null);
                mainF.SetIconStat("error", this.StatElement);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            this.Succeed=false;
            this.Result=null;
            Buffer.setVal(null);
            mainF.SetIconStat("error", this.StatElement);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        this.extract();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem with `Future#cancel()` is that subsequent calls to `get()` throw a `CancellationException`. Sometimes I still want be able to call `get()` on the `Future` in order to retrieve a partial result after the shutdown of the executor service. In that case one can implement the termination logic in the callables that you submit to the executor service. Use a field like

```
private volatile boolean terminate;

public void terminate() {
    terminate = true;
}
```

and check for `terminate` in the callable as often as required. In addition, you have to remember your callables somewhere so you can call `terminate()` on all of them.

Answer (score 6):

If you change shutdown() to shutdownNow(), you are doing the correct thing in the code that you wrote. But then, check the documentation of shutdownNow():

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.

So probably your T1 and T2 are not coded in a correct way and don't respond to the interrupt well enough. Can you maybe copy the code for them?

--

Based on your code, I guess the code that takes long time is scraper.execute(), right? So inside those method, you have to constantly check something like this:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
   throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

If the interrupt come, the InterruptedException will be thrown and catched in your catch statement and the thread will stop.

Comment: yes `scraper.execute` is the time consuming code. and 99% of time consumed by it, is the time that takes to get a web page content. the `scraper` is a library and i can't change it's code ;after that there is just one job that takes time (getting the page content) so how checking for interruption can solve the problem?

Comment: If so... you could try calling Thread.stop() to each thread, but it is really dangerous (as the javadoc explained)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Executor.[submit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method, it extends base method Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) by creating and returning a `Future` that can be used to cancel execution and/or wait for completion:

```
task = Executor.submit( T1 )
...
task.cancel( true )
```

Comment: `task.cancel( true )` also Throws exception and doesn't cancel threads!