# Abort button in ZK

Tags: zk

I want to put an Abort Label or button below...the processing message is shown in ZK. or is there any way to load my custom components instead of the default Processing. message in ZK.

Want will happen if do abort while processing is it ideal to do that, I want to do that anyways as few times my application sleeps while loading

Answer (score 0):

ZK is built on Servlets. When the busy button is shown on the ui awaiting the ajax response then the servlet thread is doing long running work on the server. Perhaps it would be possible to send another thread to interrupt the first thread but really that is high risk as all the servlet threads can end up doing long running work and no new ones will be available to cancel them.

The best solution is that long running work should not be on the servlet thread but handed off to a background thread or message queue. See [zk-asynchronous-ui-updates-and-background-processing](http://jawsy.fi/blog/2012/10/20/advanced-zk-asynchronous-ui-updates-and-background-processing-part-2/). In that example the work is offloaded to a java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService which has an API to cancel the work.

Note that cancelling of a working thread uses interruption and it is not guaranteed that code which doing the work will respond to the interrupt properly such that it is actually cancellable. The answers on the thread [cancel with executor service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023312/how-to-cancel-an-executorservice-in-java) outline some of the issues and you should test whether the work you are doing can be interrupted using the API.